# IIS : How to find requests with time out?

Tags: iis, timeout

I have an api that by using ajax i am trying to call it, but it seems to me it doesn't get to service from iis.

i am wondering how we can find requests that haven't reached to service from iis due to time out or other reasons.
is there any way to find those requests?

Answer (score 0):

If the request does not go to the server, then you can try to capture the request on the client side.

[Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/4865) is the archive versioned tool for network traffic capture and protocol analysis.

You can also use fiddler to capture network traffic.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can switch to another tool.